# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined at main.js:48

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in programming. I want to render canvas on browser

**My code is here**

```
// implement canvas js
let dataPoints = [
    {label: 'One', y: 0},
    {label: 'Two', y: 0},
    {label: 'Three', y: 0},
    {label: 'Four', y: 0}
];

const myContainer = document.querySelector(
    '#mytContainer'
);

if(cmytContainer){
    const chart = CanvasJS.Chart('mytContainer', {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: 'theme1',
        title: {
            text: 'My Results'
        },
        data: [
            {
                type: 'column',
                dataPoints: dataPoints
            }
        ]
    });
    chart.return()
}
```

Kindly some one around to help with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you call the render function? You should provide more code. Or is there a typo and "return()" should be "render()"? Are you sure you included the ChartJS library correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think error is due to if condition variable typo changed to `myContainer`

```
let dataPoints = [
    {label: 'One', y: 0},
    {label: 'Two', y: 0},
    {label: 'Three', y: 0},
    {label: 'Four', y: 0}
];

const myContainer = document.querySelector(
    '#mytContainer'
);

if(myContainer){
    const chart = CanvasJS.Chart('mytContainer', {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: 'theme1',
        title: {
            text: 'My Results'
        },
        data: [
            {
                type: 'column',
                dataPoints: dataPoints
            }
        ]
    });
    chart.return()
}
```